# The target "ContainerWaitForWarmupCompletion" does not exist in the project

Tags: msbuild

All my projects fail on this err. No change in source. Previously it was able to fix it by restarting visual studio, but now it has no effect.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4057 The target "ContainerWaitForWarmupCompletion" does not exist in the project.    my-api  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets   894
```

I've tried downgrading updated packages, update VS Code, restart both docker and VS.

Comment: The target `ContainerWaitForWarmupCompletion` is not part of MSBuild. I suspect it is from a package or an extension. Have you run a restore? Has a MSBuild extension been changed (or not installed)?

Comment: Fixed by updating Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets nuget package